# How avoid error "TypeError: invalid data type for einsum" in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, machine-learning

I try to load CSV file to numpy-array and use the array in LogisticRegression etc. Now, I am struggling with error is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression    

dataset =  pd.read_csv('../Bookie_test.csv').values
X = dataset[1:, 32:34]
y = dataset[1:, 14]

# normalize the data attributes
normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(X)
# standardize the data attributes
standardized_X = preprocessing.scale(X)

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
print(model)
# make predictions
expected = y
predicted = model.predict(X)
# summarize the fit of the model
print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

I got an error:

```
> C:\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:332:
> UserWarning: The normalize function assumes floating point values as
> input, got object   "got %s" % (estimator, X.dtype)) Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "X:/test3.py", line 23, in
> <module>
>     normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(X)   File "C:\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line
> 553, in normalize
>     norms = row_norms(X)   File "C:\Anaconda32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py", line 65,
> in row_norms
>     norms = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', X, X) TypeError: invalid data type for einsum
```

> I am new in Python and don't like transformation:

1. Load CSV to Pandas
2. Convert Pandas to NumPy
3. Use NumPy in LogisticRegression

Are there any simple approach, like:

1. Load to Pandas
2. Use Pandas Dataframes in ML methods?

Comment: I don't understand what the second half of your question has to do with the first half. The error message is pretty clear: "The normalize function assumes floating point values as input, got object", so you should check what you're reading into your dataset. Is everything in your file a number, that can be properly parsed into a number by `read_csv`?

Comment: Are there any chance to skip/ignore not `numbers` while loading csv?

Comment: The documentation gives dozens of options to read_csv; have you tried playing around with them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regarding the main question, thanks to `Evert` for advises I will check.

Regarding #2: I found great tutorial http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/11/09/python-making-scikit-learn-and-pandas-play-nice/

and achieved desired result with `pandas` + `sklearn`